# GCP queue delay

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe

I would like to make the consumer receive the message with an x-second delay (or for the topic to be made public with an x-second delay - I do not mean e.g. putting the thread to sleep in a project). Can someone advise how I could do it? Thank you in advance and best regards

Comment: An initial thought is to have a message arriving on Topic1 read by some compute (eg. Cloud Functions or Cloud Run) and then schedule a task to execute in a few seconds that puts the previously read message on Topic2.

Another thought might be to use Google Cloud Workflows ... a workflow could receive the message and then sleep for a few seconds and then publish the message to a second topic.

There is a workflow primitive to sleep ... https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/sys/sleep

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, but my preferred is Cloud Task. Create a task with your code instead of publishing a message in PubSub. Set the `schedule_time` X second in the future.

Then:

- If your consumer is configure in PUSH mode (I mean you know its endpoint URL and the message is posted to it), simply set that URL in the Cloud Task. Like that, the message will be delivered X seconds in the future
- If your consumer is in PULL mode (it listens a PubSub subscription), create a passthrough service that receive the Cloud Task invocation and republish immediately the message in a PubSub topic.

That solution is generic and versatile. You can easily change the delay for each task, according to the type, the consumer, ...